# How to import a .sql file into toad

Tags: mysql, import, toad, sqlclient

I have a .sql file, I want to import this into MySQL client, toad. I have tried importing it using command line, but it didn't work. How to import .sql file into toad?

Answer (score 2):

File/Open File/Navigate to .sql file and click open.

Answer (score 0):

We can import .sql file and execute in **Toad** using
below methods

First **create database** and then follow this steps

```
File -> Open File -> choose .sql file (find it in your computer) -> click it -> press F5 (execute the query) in Toad.
```

Successfully import .sql file in **Toad**. Thanks